# affine scheme X with exactly two points and dimension 1

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am looking for an affine scheme X with exactly two points and dim $X=1$. I am not sure if it exists, but it seems to me that it does.

I already (hopefully being right) that such a scheme with dimension 1 with exactly 1 point does not exist and it seems to me that with dimension 1 it would be possible but I can't come up with an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}X=\text{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)}\end{eqnarray} Note that there are two points $(0)$ and $(x)$ and the dimension is 1. It represents the stalk of the 1-dimensional affine space at the point $(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Take any disrete valuation ring $A$, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ or $k[x]_{(x)}$. Then $\mathrm{Spec}\,A$ is such an affine scheme.

Comment: Thank you Pavel! So in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ the only prime ideals are $(0)$ and $(p)$ right? Can you give me a hint about how I prove that they are the only ones?

Comment: Use the $p$-valuation as an Euclidean norm. This shows that the ring is PID, hence his nonzero primes are maximal, and $(p)$ is the only maximal ideal. Alternatively, it is not difficult to see that a localization of PID is again PID (by the correspondence of ideals for localization).

Comment: The symbol $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ was meant as localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $(p)$, i.e. invert everything but elements of $(p)$. Funnily enough, if one understands this symbol as $\mathbb{Z}_p$, i.e. the $p$-adic completion, the assertion still holds.